# calculate average of squared values of an array

Tags: c

I have use following code to calculate average of squared values of array. but it returns error "143 expression must have pointer to object type".

```
Int16 mono_input;
Int16 delayed_input;

double sum_sq;
double power;

int j;
int n;

delayed_input = delay_1(mono_input); //delay_1 returns sample of sound (eg 1024 samples)

for ( n = 0 ; n < 1024 ; n++)
{
  sum_sq += delayed_input [n] * delayed_inputA [n] ; //  to get the squared values of n th sample and add that to the previous value. but here it returns error 143.
}

power  = sum_sq/ 1024; // to get the average of squared values
```

Comment: What is `delayed_inputA`?

Comment: Assuming that `Int16` is not array or pointer typedef, you cannot use array syntax with `delayed_input [n]`.

Comment: Is this `c` or `c#`?

Comment: Next problem: `sum_sq` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You have typo'd the second delayed_input here:

```
sum_sq += delayed_input [n] * delayed_inputA [n] ;
```

Should be (I assume)

```
sum_sq += delayed_input [n] * delayed_input [n] ;
```